# Is it possible to generically instantiate a JS class type from an inherited factory method?

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance, static-methods

So I've been googling this for a few hours now and I can't really decide whether it's possible or not. I don't understand JS inheritance well enough to find a solution. I'm working in TypeScript, but I think this is a JavaScript issue. Platform is Node.js.

My setup is the following:

```
class Message {
    static fromBytes(bytes) {
        someChecks();
        return new Message(processedBytes);
    }
    constructor(someParameters) {
        someOtherChecks();
    }
}

class SpecificMessage extends Message {
    constructor(parameters) {
        someSpecificChecks(parameters);
    }
}
```

The background is that I get some bytes network traffic and have to check consistency before decoding it. The classes are also used to prepare new outgoing bytes (there's a `toBytes` method), which is why checksum consistency is checked in `fromBytes` and logical consistency is checked in the constructor.

What I'd like to have is an inheritable factory method that will return the respective object type. Calling `SpecificMessage.fromBytes` will return a `Message` object since it's explicitly named. I'd like to replace that object creation with something that "knows" whether I'm calling from `Message` or `SpecificMessage`. My best guess in that direction is something along the lines of `Object.create(this.prototype, {someInitLiteral})`, but I think this doesn't call the constructor?

Another thing that came up was `Object.call(this, parameters)`, but I don't think that's correct either. Is there a way to instantiate the current class from the "generic" static method?

Worst case I was thinking about just calling `super.fromBytes` and create a new `SpecificMessage` from the contained data. That would construct two objects but go through all the checks.

Thank your for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you seem to have realised, the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) would refer to the constructor (= the (sub)class) inside the static method<sup>1</sup>. So you can just call that with `new`:

```
class Message {
    static fromBytes(bytes) {
        someChecks();
        return new this(processedBytes);
//             ^^^^^^^^
    }
    constructor(someParameters) {
        // …
    }
}
```

<sub>1: As long as it is called as a method on the respective class. You can no longer easily pass it around [as a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572).</sub>

Comment: Oh, so close. Thanks!